# What is the best way to load static objects in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, static-data

I have a list of about 100 address.  I want to use the [CLGeocoder Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CLGeocoder)
and the geocodeAddressDictionary or geocodeAddressString methods to get a list of CLPlacemarks for each address.  I don't want the app to do this every time it starts up (as the addresses never change and it requires internet).  How can I statically store a list of 100 CLPlacemark objects to be loaded each time the app launches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest:

Store the list in your app bundle as a .plist file or a JSON file which can then be parsed on launch into a static NSDictionary or as an instance variable of a Singleton object.

First serialise your 100 addresses into a JSON file. You can try use some online tools like: http://www.objgen.com/json

Once you have a text JSON file drag the file into your project in Xcode. You can then parse it using:

```
NSError *error;
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Addresses" ofType:@"json"];  
NSURL *localFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
NSData *contentOfLocalFile = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:localFileURL];
NSDictionary *addresses = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:contentOfLocalFile 
                                            options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers 
                                              error:&error];
```

You can use same method to deserialise PLIST file.

Comment: @user2662692 it's courtesy to reward those that help you out, if they indeed resolve your issue....just saying.

Comment: @soulshined relax... it wouldn't let me mark it as the answer that early